# How can we get the total amount of cancel order after successful order cancellation in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

Magento 2.1.10 - I want the total amount of cancel order after successful order cancellation with customer wise.

Comment: for particular customer or total of all orders which are cancles /

Comment: for a particular customer